# Why is it common to say "The Ukraine"?

Tags: names, toponyms

As far as I am aware no other countried are used an article before them, but people usually refer to Ukraine as "The Ukraine".

Why?

Comment: Lots of other countries use (or used) an article, including The Lebanon, The Congo, The Gambia, The Sudan, The Yemen...

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Never heard 'the Lebanon' or 'the Yemen', but I would add 'the UK', 'the United Arab Emirates', and 'the US' to your list, along with 'the USSR' when it existed - and that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: I deliberately excluded countries which include some sort of adjective, or where a noun like "Republic" can be distinguished with *The*. My list is simply those which take the definite article with **just** a name. [Relevant blog post](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2007/04/gambia-lebanon-etc.html)